# Can I repair water damage under the kitchen sink with a sintra panel?

Tags: repair, wood, water, damage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair water damage under the kitchen sink?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15222/how-can-i-repair-water-damage-under-the-kitchen-sink)

I found out that our kitchen water connection had somehow loosened up and was leaking water on the floor undernieth the sink.  Now the particle board cabnet floor is warped quite a bit.  I was thinking about cutting it out and placing a [Sintra®](http://tri-dee.com/sintra_plastic_pvc.htm) material as a new floor.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to do this and if it's a good idea to replace the main plywood too.  Or only replace the the main floor wood if it's really fried.