# How can I repair water damage under the kitchen sink?

Tags: wood, water, replacement, particle-board

I found out that our kitchen water connection had somehow loosened up and was leaking water on the floor underneath the sink. Now the particle board cabinet floor is warped quite a bit. I was thinking about cutting it out and placing a [Sintra®](http://tri-dee.com/sintra_plastic_pvc.htm) material as a new floor.
Does anyone have any suggestions how to do this and if it's a good idea to replace the main floor plywood too. Or only replace the main floor wood if it's really fried?  How or what tools would you recommend I use to cut out the old wood/particle board?

Answer (score 4):

1. There is a sub-panel between the bottom of the cabinet and the
   actual floor. Measure the board so you can create a new one (You can
   also get a piece of cardboard to create a template to cut from -
   works great with a cabinet with many angles.). To remove it (since
   it's particle board) you can just break it out with a hammer. **Be
   careful not to damage the spacer board that helps support the middle
   of the panel. If you damage it or if it's in bad shape, you'll need
   to cut a new piece to replace it.
2. When you measure and cut the new board, you will most likely need to
   cut it half to get it under the sink. You'll need to figure this out
   and make sure to add a quarter inch (width of the saw blade) to the
   width of the new board to compensate for the cut in the middle.
   Again, you might need to put in a space board in the center for
   added support. You'll also need consider where the pipes come in which might be from the floor from the wall. If from the wall, it will of course be easier.
3. Once the new board is in, you can use the Sintra panels. Or get a
   piece of linoleum to cover it so you can help prevent water under
   the sink as well as hide the center cut (Or any bad cuts you might
   have made in the process). You could also get the 12"x12" adhesive
   panels.

**Tools**

- drill,
- skill saw or table saw,
- possibly a jig-saw
- tape measure
- **safety glasses**.

**Hardware**

- screws
- maybe nails